# SMTPAuthenticationError Django

Tags: django, email, authentication, smtp, gmail

I was trying to send a verification email at my program, when I use gmail it works and send the verification email but now im trying to use my own mail server and it started to raise this error

SMTPAuthenticationError at /accounts/register/

(535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:')

any idea why?

```
 # EMAIL SETTINGS
    EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.xxxx.xxx"
    EMAIL_PORT = "25"
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = "no-reply@xxxxx.net"
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # Controls whether a secure connection is used.
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 

    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: I have the same error when I using my server, do you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Verify the username and password are exactly the same, 
Do not give full e-Mail id if in case your smtp accepts just the username without domain

e.g. 
e-Mail id : username@abc.com
in settings file, just give username when your smtp accepts it.